Defining proper latency values in the proper places in linux to gain performance
Ok, I think I figured out why my server responds somewhat slow. due to bufferbloat.
So I did some math at my end, and it turns out I need to have a buffer of almost 4K worth of packets (instead of 54K). But when I explore my system I found several places where I can define buffers as follows:
Defining output buffer:

via ethtool and setting TX value
via txqueuelen parameter of ifconfig

Defining input buffer:

via ethtool and setting RX value
via /proc/sys/net/core/netdev_max_backlog

I believe the buffers per direction are summed together since I believe the packets go through them both (hardware and software buffer).
As my buffer requirement is small, it can fit in the hardware buffer via ethtool.
Is it better to set the buffers through the ethernet hardware itself while making the linux software buffers really small (maybe between 0 and 100), or is it better to make the hardware buffers small while setting the linux software buffers large and why?
I'm asking this to try to make my server perform faster without having to resort to CPU overclocking.
I have also computed by buffer needs based on the assumption of a 50mS latency to connect to the server), from a ethtool reporting that the connection speed is 1000mb/s and that the MTU is 1500 bytes.laten

How bad is it, what evidence do you have that the problem is bufferbloat? Ideal tests show bandwidth and latency numbers in the same tool under load, bufferbloat project recommends  https://flent.org/  among others.
